# How to apply class to <td> with reference to the word mentioned in <p class>

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan="1">
        <p class="Hello-7-blue1">Hello Stack Overflow1</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="2">
        <p class="Hello-red">Hello Stack Overflow2</p>
        <p class="Hello-6-tab-red">defines red color,that class want to 
 apply 
 to</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <p class="Hello-world-6-orange">Hello Stack Overflow3</p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
function convertClassName(src) {
return src.replace(/^.*?-/, "");
}

$("table p").each(function() {
$(this).closest("td").addClass(convertClassName(this.className));
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected output:

```
<td class="blue1">
<p class="Hello-7-blue1">
<td class="red">
<p class="Hello-6-tab-red">
```

From above question, i want to apply the class mentioned in

(i.e,p class="Hello-7-blue1") should be applied to its closest (i.e td class="blue1").

instead of Dash "-",if i use Underscore"_" then its working,but in my page there is Dash. so please can can one help me out

Comment: Maybe I totally misunderstand the question but try replacing your regex with `/^.*[\-_]/`. Let me know if this is what you're looking for and I'll turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression should be changed as per given below:

```
function convertClassName(src) {
return src.replace(/^.*-/, ""); //<-- Note change here
}
```

Comment: actually can we do for both ,

i.e Hello-7-blue


it should be work for both dash as well as underscore.
And Hello-7_blue.

Comment: For it, you should use this regex: `src.replace(/^.*-/, "").replace(/^.*_/, "");`

Answer (score 0):

use split function instead of regex replace your function

```
function convertClassName(src) {
return src.replace(/^.*?-/, "");
}
```

with

```
function convertClassName(src) {
    //alert(src);
    return src.split("-")[src.split("-").length-1];
}
```